Issues with ODBC Connection in Integration Services Using Visual Studio
I'm trying to make an ODBC connection in Integration Services using Visual Studio. I want to transfer data from a PostgreSQL table to SQL Server. I encounter a problem during the table loading phase... in the connection manager, it shows the tables from the database. But when I click on "Columns" on the side, it remains empty... I have no idea what could be causing this. https://imgur.com/a/qG8jp8h
enter image description here enter image description here
I want to be able to load the tables from PostgreSQL to SQL Server.

Found out that using ADO .NET source solved this issue in our case.

First check which ODBC connection you are using try with both 32 bit and 64 bit one by one.
